# Creating a KnockoutJS-like tracker in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, knockout.js, key-value-observing, observable

So I'm basically just trying to add watchers to Javascript's Getter/Setter functions but having no luck yet.

KnockoutJS (http://knockoutjs.com) does this with `.track()`.

A YouTube video example of `track()` in use:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNiUcuo3Wio

This leads me to my first question, **does `__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__` only apply to objects and not string literals?**

Here's a code example of how this would ideally work, it may clarify some things.

```
// Knockout-like tracker in NodeJS.

function track(trackObj, callback) {

  if (!trackObj) return;

  trackObj.__defineCallback__ = callback;

  trackObj.__defineGetter__('value', function() {
    return 'something';
  });

  trackObj.__defineSetter__('value', function() {
    console.log("fn called");
    if (trackObj.__defineCallback__)
      trackObj.__defineCallback__("new value");
  });

}

var something = "track me!";

track(something, function(newValue) {
  console.log("Something has changed to: " + newValue);
});

something = "I have changed."; // Trigger the update callback function.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple solution although I'm not quite happy with it. For that reason, I'll leave this question as unanswered for now.

One of the disadvantages is that you can only track a single property with the same name. To get around this, you could put the following code in NodeJS module and create a new tracker object for each item you'd like to track. This would work with same named variables too. Handling all of the different tracker objects could get confusing though.

```
var tracker = {};
var trackerValues = {};

function track(trackName, callback) {

  Object.defineProperty(tracker, trackName, {

    set: function(toValue) {
      trackerValues[trackName] = toValue;
      if (callback) callback();
    },

    get: function() {
      return trackerValues[trackName];
    }

  });
}

tracker.something = "track me!";

track("something", function() {
  console.log("Something has changed to: " + tracker.something);
});

track("somethingElse", function() {
  console.log("SomethingElse has changed to: " + tracker.somethingElse);
});

tracker.something = "I have changed.";
tracker.something = "I have changed again!";
tracker.somethingElse = "We can track multiple objects";
```

And a JSBin example of this working:
http://jsbin.com/bunonaca/1/edit?js,console